# Nullpointer exception for Long variable

Tags: java

I have the following code

```
private Long projectNumber; // with getters and setters
```

and when I am checking whether `projectNumber` is null or not, I am getting null pointer exception at the if condition

```
if(selected.getProjectNumber()!=null){

// do something

}
```

What could be the reason for this even though Long is a wrapper class.

If I change projectNumber from Long to String, it works fine.

Update 1

```
private Project selected = new Project();

public Project getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Project selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
```

I am getting selected value in ManagedBean of JSF in the following method

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {

}
```

projectNo getters and setters

```
public Long getProjectNo() {
            return projectNo;
        }

        public void setProjectNo(Long projectNo) {
            this.projectNo = projectNo;
        }
```

Comment: You'll get the same exception if you write `null.getProjectNumber()` (`selected` is `null`)

Comment: Your long is not a variable, but a Wrapper class for a primitive value. Therefor, it can be uninitialized. Accessing a method of the wrapper class without initializing it first results in a NullPointerException.

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE if the getter returns a `long` instead of a `Long`, isn't it? But I think as OP has the variable as a `Long`, he did declare the getter to return that too...

Comment: Please post the getter method! It seems something strange is going on around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that `selected` is null. Check it like:

```
if(selected != null && selected.getProjectNumber()!=null){

   // do something

} else {
   // here: selected = null OR projectNumber of selected is null
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have is because `selected` is null, `projectNumber`. Change the check to something like:

```
if(selected != null && selected.getProjectNumber()!=null){

// do something

}
```

Or alternatively add a separate check for `selected` above.

Answer (score 2):

If you get an NPE here:

```
if(selected.getProjectNumber()!=null){
```

and all `getProjectNumber()` does is `return projectNumber`, this strongly indicates that **`selected` is `null`**.

Comment: If I change `projectNumber` from `Long` to `String`, it works fine.

Comment: @Polppan: Then there's something else going on in your code that you're not telling us about. Please show a complete, runnable example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From what you posted, it sems that the problem is that the object referred by the `selected` variable is `null`. You have to check that too:

```
if(selected !=null && selected.getProjectNumber()!=null){

    // do something

}
```

**Explanation:** Doing it this way, as the boolean AND (and the OR) operator evaluates only the left condition if it is false, not touching the right side, you won't get a `NullPointerExceptyion` anymore.

**EDIT** As OP mentioned that by changing the variable to `String` the problem is not encountered, as 0xCAFEBABE's suggestion implies, the same error might be possible if the getter returns (or somehow internally uses) a simple `long` value instead of a `Long` object, and the value of the variable is `null`:

```
/** error getter */
public long getProjectNumber() { 
    //this would trz to convert null, but what will it convert to? A NullPointerExecption...
    return projectNumber;
}
```

Comment: For some strange reason `selected` is `null`, if `projectNumber` is `String` then `selected` is `not null`

Comment: @Polppan please post the getter method too. Also, it would be nice to see how you obtain the `selected`.

Comment: I have included getter and setter for selected in my question as update 1

Comment: Ok, those seem to be fine. Please post getProjectNumber() too.

Comment: Included that as well in my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

did you check if `selected` is `null`

you can do the following

```
if(null != selected)
{
    if(null != selected.getProjectNumber())
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your object selected is apparently null, try to do:

```
if ((selected != null) && (selected.getProjectNumber()!=null)){

// do something

}
```